# Как запретить индексацию для произвольного типа записи?

Tags: поисковые-системы, поисковая-оптимизация

Как запретить индексацию для произвольного типа записи?
Если это не сложно, подскажите пожалуйста, как это сделать без плагина, или подскажите, какой нужен плагин для этого?
Такой вариант правильный, т.е. если расположить этот код в header.php?

```
<?php 
if( 'your-post-type' === get_post_type() ){
  print '<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант правильный, вот только capslock я бы убрал, как-то не принято...